# Foursquare userless search iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, rest, foursquare

is there a way to fetch the venues search in iOS without the user entering his password or showing some foursquare oauth website?

I don't think that this oAuth makes any sense for this kind of request, it should be just an REST api like so "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=-27.58818,-48.523248&client_id=JN00ABQBOCK5V54FQ1TWQFLOOIDU12UAZXURHXGXNK0ESJBY&client_secret=14ES1NXTCL1XC5HSLBUT4LWE4ROEDGNYKKWGGERZQGUKQ5JC"

but this one is deprecated =/

Any thoughts?

Comment: do not share your original client_id & Secret publicly ... !!

Answer (score 3):

It's not deprecated, you're just missing the "versioning" parameter that specifies what version of the API you're trying to use.

Requesting https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=-27.58818,-48.523248&client_id=JN00ABQBOCK5V54FQ1TWQFLOOIDU12UAZXURHXGXNK0ESJBY&client_secret=14ES1NXTCL1XC5HSLBUT4LWE4ROEDGNYKKWGGERZQGUKQ5JC**&v=20111107** will remove the warning you saw in your response

Answer (score 1):

Add a query string parameter to your request as follows..

```
&v=20111119 // Choose a proper version.
```

**Update**: this is actually a date. So make sure you send current date in yyyymmdd format against v parameter.

Answer (score 0):

According to [FourSquare's docs page on venue searching](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search.html) an acting user is no longer necessary:

> Some endpoints (e.g. venue search) allow you to not act as any
>   particular user. We will return unpersonalized data suitable for
>   generic use, and the performance should be slightly better. In these
>   cases, pass your client ID as client_id and your client secret as
>   client_secret. Although the draft 11 of the OAuth2 spec provides a
>   mechanism for consumers to act via token entitled Client Credentials,
>   we do not currently support this.